# How to delete image(element) from canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am developing hotel floor view using canvas with the help of kinetic js.I want to provide an option to delete current dragged,dropped image on canvas.

this is my code for only drag drop of image and not with delete option :

```
// get a reference to the house icon in the toolbar
// hide the icon until its image has loaded
var $house=$("#house");
$house.hide();

// get the offset position of the kinetic container
var $stageContainer=$("#container");
var stageOffset=$stageContainer.offset();
var offsetX=stageOffset.left;
var offsetY=stageOffset.top;

// create the Kinetic.Stage and layer
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: 350,
  height: 350
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

// start loading the image used in the draggable toolbar element
// this image will be used in a new Kinetic.Image
var image1=new Image();
image1.onload=function(){
  $house.show();
}
image1.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/4top.png";

// make the toolbar image draggable
$house.draggable({
  helper:'clone',
});

// set the data payload
$house.data("url","house.png"); // key-value pair
$house.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
$house.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
$house.data("image",image1); // key-value pair

// make the Kinetic Container a dropzone
$stageContainer.droppable({
  drop:dragDrop,
});

// handle a drop into the Kinetic container
function dragDrop(e,ui){

  // get the drop point
  var x=parseInt(ui.offset.left-offsetX);
  var y=parseInt(ui.offset.top-offsetY);

  // get the drop payload (here the payload is the image)
  var element=ui.draggable;
  var data=element.data("url");
  var theImage=element.data("image");

  // create a new Kinetic.Image at the drop point
  // be sure to adjust for any border width (here border==1)
  var image = new Kinetic.Image({
    name:data,
    x:x,
    y:y,
    image:theImage,
    draggable: true
  });
  layer.add(image);
  layer.draw();
}
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
#toolbar{
  width:350px;
  height:35px;
  border:solid 1px blue;
}
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<h4>Drag from toolbar onto canvas. Then drag around canvas.</h4>
<div id="toolbar">
  <img id="house" width=32 height=32 src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/4top.png"><br>
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kinetic to `image.remove()`, then `layer.draw()` to refresh the canvas, in similar fashion to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883123/kinetic-js-removing-image-from-canvas-on-click-of-a-button-outside-the-canvas).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to temporarily remove an image (and later re-add it) you use:

```
// temporarily remove the image from the layer
yourImage.remove();
yourLayer.draw();

// and later re-add it
yourLayer.add(yourImage);
yourLayer.draw();
```

But if you want to permanently delete the image (and recover all its resources) you use:

```
// permanently delete the image and reclaim all the resources it used
yourImage.destroy();
yourLayer.draw();
```